# Titanium tabs accumulating when opening new windows

Tags: tabs, titanium

I have a list of courses in rows like this:
[image: rows of courses]

Whenever I click a row, a new tab is created, and a new window is added to that tab showing the course info.

Then if I press back, it goes back to the courses window, which is great, but when I click another course it adds that to the list of tabs, so it starts looking like this:

[image: Course Info tabs are accumulating]

Whereas, there should only be two tabs here, the Courses tab and Get Courses tab.

---

In get_courses.js (the file that deals with making the rows) I have this event listener which creates a new tab every time a row is clicked (which I'm sure is where my mistake is, I'm just not sure how to fix it):

```
table.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    var courseInfo_window = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
        title:e.rowData.title,
        url:'get_courseInfo.js',
        courseIMISCode: e.rowData.courseIMISCode
    });

    var courseInfo_tab = Titanium.UI.createTab({
        title:'Course Info',
        window:courseInfo_window
    });
    Titanium.UI.currentTabGroup.addTab(courseInfo_tab); 
});
```

Which I want to be there to create a Course Info tab, but then in get_courseInfo.js I have this, possibly redundant code:

```
Ti.UI.currentTabGroup.activeTab.open(courseInfo_window);
```

Which, in my noob mind seems necessary to open my courseInfo_window, but is accumulating the tabs in the bottom (as shown in the image earlier).

**TL;DR:** What do I need to do (probably in get_courses.js) to update the Course Info tab instead of opening a new tab for each row click?

Answer (score 0):

You can access tabs in TabGroup through [tabs property](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TabGroup-property-tabs). However, it would be easier to keep reference to tab which you created outside of event listener and modify inside:

```
var courseInfo_tab = null;

table.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    var courseInfo_window = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
        title:e.rowData.title,
        url:'get_courseInfo.js',
        courseIMISCode: e.rowData.courseIMISCode
    });
    if (courseInfo_tab === null) {
        courseInfo_tab = Titanium.UI.createTab({
            title:'Course Info',
            window:courseInfo_window
        });
        Titanium.UI.currentTabGroup.addTab(courseInfo_tab); 
    } else {
        courseInfo_tab.window = courseInfo_window;
    } 
});
```

Comment: I get an error on courseInfo_tab.window = courseInfo_window; "'null' is not an object..." I think it's because the tab is actually created inside the if, so it's not created in the else. So how do I reference a tab that already exists?